# Why my CPU never work on the maximum multiplier

Tags: intel-core-i5

I have Intel Core i5 9400F installed on my system. I found that it never works on the maximum x41 multiplier. I see the following when CPU-Z benchmark is running:

[image: CPU-Z]

Can I force it to work on the maximum speed, does it depend on the system / BIOS configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Intel intentionally markets this cpu as Base freq = 2.90 GHz . Max Turbo Frequency is indeed 4.1 ghz, but that is met only under specific scenarios. Most likely you would hit that with only one (maybe two) cores active, not like in your screenshot when all cores are fired.